# Regular expression to find files that match a pattern in R

Tags: regex, r

I am experiencing some difficulties with Regular expression in R.

I am looking for all files that match the following pattern:

the files name should start with "11" and ends with ".JPG"

What regular expression should I use?

```
list.files(path='my_path', pattern=???)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `^` to indicate "at the start", `$` to indicate "at the end", and `.*` for all the stuff in between, so you can try something like:

```
list.files(path='my_path', pattern="^11.*\\.JPG$")
```

---

Try this little experiment out and see how the results of each pattern differs:

```
someFiles <- c("testpost.html", "mytest.html", "testing.html", "testing.txt")
grep("test", someFiles)
grep("^test", someFiles)
grep("\\.txt", someFiles)
grep("^test.*\\.html", someFiles)
```

Comment: @SimonO101, yes boss. I was just about to ask you if I should just delete my answer and let you post your comment.

Comment: +1 Hey no way. You additionally typed up an explanation of *how it works* (something I am becoming a bit lazy about of late). Worth the 24 seconds delay methinks! :-)